# Controlling node.js application's events via external website

Tags: javascript, node.js, authentication

I'm creating my first nodejs app. I wanted to ask for a idea for safe controlling node.js application from external website(server)...

Explanation:
Im running steambot on a server... The bot can chat/trade/etc.

On my website (example.com/bot) ive got actions: trade 'these' items with 'this' person... I used simple POST form without authentication, that is pretty dumb, but Im trying.

Question:
What is the best way to tell the bot what to do via only my website (since the POST form you can copy an use whereever you want) + to send information as JSON object f.e.

Thanks ! ^^

Comment: Your questions feels a bit too broad. As you've just said, making the bot's web service accept instructions via POST messages is fine. But there are quite many solutions for the issue of authenticating your website to the bot. I would suggest you to look into that and write a more specific question if you stumble into problems on the way.

Comment: I honestly do not think the question was that broad, just poorly worded. Obviously I was able to figure what he wanted since he accepted my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMO, your best bet would be to use a realtime communication library like [socket.io](http://socket.io).

Server:

```
var app = require('http').createServer(handler)
var io = require('socket.io')(app);
io.on('connection', function (socket) {
  socket.on('trade', function (data) {
    // Make your server-side bot do stuff
    bot.doTrade(data.itemId, data.userId);
  });
});
```

Client:

```
<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script>
  var socket = io('http://localhost');
  $('#tradeBtn').click(function () {
    socket.emit('trade', { itemId: 123, userId: 456 });
  });
</script>
```

Socket.io uses multiple methods of communication with the server behind the scenes. It will first try to use [websockets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket) and if that fails it will fall back on [server-sent events](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_serversentevents.asp) or [long-polling](http://www.pubnub.com/blog/http-long-polling/) if necessary. The nice thing about socket.io is that you don't have to worry about that much; it just takes care of it for you. You can listen for and emit events from both the client and server to facilitate realtime communication between the server and client page.